# Running a windows task scheduler job on Azure webjob (scheduled event)

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, windows-task-scheduler, azure-appservice

I have a question on windows task scheduler job running on Azure.

I already have a console app that is ought to run as a windows task scheduler job (5th day of every month).
I was finding options to run it on Azure and found function app or webjob.
Since I already have the console application, community suggests to go with Azure webjob and that webjob can be run on the existing app service.

I'm confused here, My current situation is, I do have a webapi running on Azure api app service.

1. does it mean I can run it under the existing api app service? If yes, if the webjob (windows task scheduler job) takes more than 5 hours of time to finish its job, are webapi requests get blocked?

   I can bring the console app projects and web api projects to one roof (solution), so that I can build the solution and get the deployment packages using DevOps pipelines.
2. How can I deploy to the webjob from the azure pipelines?

Kindly let me know if I'm heading in a wrong direction to attack the problem.

Comment: Thanks James Z for editing my question.
I apologize for not writing a effective one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

q1 - no, they run in different threads.
q2 - there are many blogs online about that, you'd need to build\publish your artifacts and then use deploy Azure Web App task or write custom powershell code to do that

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround, I will explore further on the deployment strategies since I just learnt both run on different threads.
Thanks again.